# Standard horizontal padding size for UILabel

Tags: ios, ipad, uilabel, padding

First of all I am sorry if my question is not directly related to coding. But I did some research online before asking the question here and couldn't get the answer so looking for you help.

I am trying to find the Apple standards for horizontal and vertical padding size of a UILabel on iPad. I am working on an app while has a popover table view controller and has some UILabel cells. I wanted to be in sync with the standard padding size used by Apple for iPad and don't want to add any custom one.

Is there a way to find the standard size? I couldn't get through the number in the human interface docs on Apple developer site.

Comment: I found the answer may be not a direct one but could be a workaround. Check the standard option and then uncheck it. It leaves a standard size on the size box while working with auto layout.